# How to apply different text styling in same sentence?

Tags: html, css

So I have a `<h1>`like this:

```
<h1>Hello my name is: (variable name)</>
```

I want a bold H1, but I want the variable name to be lighter.

I though a good way to do this was to do:

```
<h1>Hello my name is:</h1><h1 id="changeName">Variable Name</h1>
```

Then style both separately. However, doing it like this I can't get the text in one sentence.

Comment: use `<span></span>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider using an other element inside your `<h1>`. This way, you don't have to use the `<h1>` tag twice.

```
<h1>Hello my name is:<span class="changeName">Variable Name</span></h1>
```

The advantage of the `<span>` element is that it won't change the styling except for what you give it through CSS explicitly.

Also, please prefer class attributes above id attributes, it will make your styling more general if you decide to add similar styling to other elements in the future.

Comment: Thanks that works indeed :)

Shouldn't it be an ID if I know it will only be used once though?

Comment: You're welcome! To be honest, it's just my general advice. If you only use it once, by all means, go ahead and use the ID attribute :)

Answer (score 0):

Use span tags, and style the span accordingly:

```
    <h1>Hello my name is: <span>Variable Name</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add an inline element for the text you want to highlight. This could be 
`<em> | <span> | <b>`
Whatever makes sense to you.

Then in css target the element

```
h1 > em {font-weight: bold;}
```